# Make Scrollbar viable for Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, scroll, scrollbar

I would like to make my css scrollbar of a div visible for Firefox. I can see that it doesn't work on firefox but it is working on chrome. 
Here is my css.

```
.ascenseur::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 4px;
}
.ascenseur::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #7997cd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken but I believe currently the only CSS that mozilla supports for scrollbar styling is:

```
scrollbar-color: red green; (where red is the bar and green is thumb)
scrollbar-width: thin; (other option is thick)
```

There are some javascript scrollbar options that can be use to style Mozilla scrollers but I don't have much experience with them.

what you could do is something like:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix('') {
  .ascenseur {
    scrollbar-color: #7997cd green; (pick something not green)
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

This would apply the alternative style to mozilla *(firefox)* only and allow other browsers to use your original style.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars